# Asp.Net Link Popularity Checking Script

Tags: asp.net, seo

I want to get link popularity of supplied link that will show inbound and outbound links means how many links are exchanged with the supplied link and with how many links that link is exchanged, i want to get this in Asp.Net. Can anyone guide me how can i get this? or supply some ready made script for this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a like you may be trying to reinvent the wheel. Have you looked at Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    ' Save the referrer Url
    ' Use now the Request.UrlReferrer variable to do what you want to do
End If
```

I also found a very interesting blog post on dunno.org "[Logging HTTP Referals with ASP.NET](http://idunno.org/articles/279.aspx)" written in c#.